# How to override equals in base and child class

Tags: java, overriding, equals

I have one example where I have overriden `equals` methods in both base class and child class.

```
package com.test;

public class Point2D {

    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;

    public Point2D(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (x + " " + y);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (Point2D.class != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((o instanceof Point2D)) {
            if ((((Point2D) o).x == this.x) && (((Point2D) o).y == this.y)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return x + y;
    }

}

class TestPoint2D {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Point2D d2 = new Point2D(2, 4);
        Point2D d3 = new Point2D(2, 4);
        Point3D d4 = new Point3D(2, 4, 5);
        Point3D d5 = new Point3D(2, 4, 5);
        System.out.println(d2.equals(d3));
        System.out.println(d3.equals(d5));
        System.out.println(d5.equals(d3));
        System.out.println(d4.equals(d5));
    }

}

class Point3D extends Point2D {

    private int z = 0;

    public Point3D(int x, int y, int z) {

        super(x, y);
        this.z = z;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if ((o instanceof Point3D)) {
            if ((((Point3D) o).z == this.z)) {
                Point2D obj = (Point2D) o;
                return super.equals(obj);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode() + z;
    }

}
```

While testing I'm getting output :

```
true
false
false
false
```

The expected output is :

```
true
false
false
true
```

Could anyone tell me what is missing here ?

Comment: Did you step through the code in the debugger?  You should know to do that before posting here, given your rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you saw, your code declares two equal `Point3D` objects (subclass objects) not equal, here `d4` and `d5`. I think this is because of this if statement in `Point2D.equals()`:

```
    if (Point2D.class != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
```

`o` is `d5`, so its `getClass()` returns `Point3D.class`, not the same as `Point2D.class`. The result returned is also returned from `Point3D.equals()` and is printed. I think that instead you want

```
    if (getClass() != o.getClass()) {
```

Jim Garrison is correct, of course, that you can use a debugger to discover.

Comment: True. I know, why I'm getting that unexpected output. But, I was unable to resolve it. Thanks for your help.